# Clipboard manager with Pantheon integration

Tags: pantheon

I'm looking for a clipboard manager that integrates well with Pantheon desktop. Can someone make any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean integrate well with Pantheon-desktop ?

I have been using Glipper for quite some time now. It's working fine.

```
sudo apt-get install glipper
```

Go ahead. Try it out.

Comment: My mistake! Fixed. Yes, I've already installed glipper but I see no trace of it in wingpanel despite I've rebooted.That's why I meant with the good integration.

Comment: Ok, I see I can launch it from the terminal.

Comment: Add it to your startup programs list in Applications section in Settings

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install glipper [...] E: Unable to locate package glipper` so it seems like it is no longer part of the distribution :-(

Answer (score 5):

You can use "Clippy" docklet in the dock (Plank).

Open Plank preferences by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and right/secondary clicking on Plank (or just run `plank --preferences` in the Terminal) and go to Docklets tab.

[image]

Drag and drop Clippy icon to the dock. Right-click on it will open simply clipboard manager.

Comment: Thank you, this is clean! In my opinion as long the stock app is good, I will try to love that one, sometime storage are precious for dual boot OS :D

Comment: Is there any way to use Clippy with some keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

I recommended this one, my favorite clipboard manager for elementary https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.davidmhewitt.clipped.desktop

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Clipped](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.davidmhewitt.clipped) which you can install directly from the App Center.

Comment: I don't see it. I see just a 10 $ app called Clips :)

Comment: Try compiling from the source. I did and worked :) Just follow the instruction in [Clipped Repo](https://github.com/davidmhewitt/clipped). You may need to install some packages.

Answer (score 0):

For elementary OS 6 users that want to use Clipped, you need to compile and install it directly from the source code.

The compile and install steps are easy as follow:

1. `sudo apt install meson libgtk-3-dev valac libsqlite3-dev libgee-0.8-dev`
2. `git clone https://github.com/davidmhewitt/clipped`
3. `cd clipped`
4. `meson build --prefix=/usr`
5. `cd build`
6. `ninja`
7. `sudo ninja install`